# How do i use a second value from my toArray function in laravel when creating a notification

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-notification

I'm trying to get a users email and use it in my html code but I'm not sure how to do this, at the moment this is my code:

```
public function toArray($notifiable) 
{
    return [
        'data' => $this->user->name. ' commented on your post',
    ];
}
```

I am able to use the first line 'data'...
in the following way:

```
{{ $notification->data['data'] }}
```

but I'm struggling to figure out how to use the email.

How would I do this?

At the moment I am using `{{ $notification->data['data'] }}` to get the name of the user that makes a comment on another user post.

When a user makes this comment, the posts owner receives a notification that looks like this:

[image: how its supposed to look]

but I need to add the name of the user that commented on the post before the 'commented on your post' text and I need the email to generate the profile picture.

I can use the email if I change the code above to:

```
'data' => $this->user->email
```

and I can use the name if I change the code to:

```
'data' => $this->user->name
```

but if I use one I cant use the other or at least i don't know how to.

so I'm asking how do I change it so that I can use both the email and name at the same time?

Comment: You should use the [toMail()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/notifications#mail-notifications) method. The `toArray()` method is used for database or broadcasting.

Comment: i only need the email to generate an image to add to a notification not to send an email

Comment: Oh, ok. Could you provide bit more information about what you're trying to achieve and how you're currently planning to achieve it.

Comment: I have provided more info above.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now. When you said "email" I though you meant an actual email not an email address. The answer below should be what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you control that data you should be able to format it how you want:

```
public function toArray($notifiable) {
    return [
        'commenter' => [
            'name' => $this->user->name,
            'email' => $this->user->email,
        ],
        'message' => $this->user->name. ' commented on your post',
    ];
}

$notification->data['commenter']['email'] // email
$notification->data['message']            // message
```

Comment: if i do that i get the following error: Illegal string offset 'email'

Comment: @es915 when calling what you get that?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: what line of code that you are calling gives you that error

Comment: In this line: <li>{{$notification->data['message']}}</li>

Comment: Now im getting: Undefined index: commenter

Comment: can you do a dump of `$notification->data` to see what it looks like

Comment: do i do that in the html file or the toArray() function

Comment: i get: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given if i do a dump on $notification->data

Comment: its working now, i just cleared the old notifications and creates new ones with the above code you provided and its working fine now thank you for the help.